# Pointwise convergence of vanishing at infinity function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function that vanishes at infinity. Using the supremum norm, I was wondering about the pointwise convergence of $\lambda^{n}f(x+n)$ where $\lambda>0$.

I was thinking since $f$ vanishes at infinity then we can find a sequence starting after $N\geq n$ large enough so that $|f(x+N)|<|\lambda|^{-2N}$. If this is the case then, $|\lambda|^N|f(x+N)|<|\lambda|^{-N}\to 0$ as $N\to \infty.$ Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why should $f$ decay exponentially fast? Consider for example $\lambda=2,f(x)=1/x \chi_{[1,\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: @Ian Sure, but I’ve been trying to come up with a counter example for a function that is continuous on the positive semi axis. No luck.

Comment: Then use $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1} \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$, works just as well. All that really mattered about the above example was the behavior at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda =2$ and $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ then $\lambda^{n}f(x+n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.